# creating python server in AWS without breaching free tier

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sagemaker

Just a conceptual question here.

I'm a newbie to aws. I have a node app and a python file that is currently on a Flask server. The node app sends data to the Py server and gets data back. This takes approx 3.2 secs to happen. I am not sure how I can apply this to AWS. I tried sagemaker but it was really costly for me. Is there anyway I can create a Python server with an endpoint in AWS within the free tier?

Thanks

Rushi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use sagemaker to deploy your flask application to AWS. AWS has a nice documentation to deploy a Flask Application to an [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) environment.

Other than that you can also deploy the application using two methods.

1. via EC2
2. via Lambda

#### EC2 Instances

You can launch the ec2 instance with public IP with SSH enabled from your IP address. Then SSH into the instance and install the python, it's libraries and your application.

#### Lambda

AWS lambda is the perfect solution. It scales automatically, depends upon the requests your application will receive.
As lambda needs your dependencies be available in the package, so you need to install them using `--target` parameter, zip the python code along with the installed packages and then upload to the Lambda.

```sh
pip install --target ./package Flask
cd package
zip -r9 function.zip . # Create a ZIP archive of the dependencies.
cd .. && zip -g function.zip lambda_function.py # Add your function code to the archive.
```

For more detailed instructions you can read these documentations

- [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html)